# Setting user environment variable and apply it to new processes

Tags: linux, environment-variables, bash

I'm trying to set a global environment variable by adding it to the `.bash_profile`.

What can I do (other than restarting), to apply this value globally, so that new processes (such as Eclipse) can access this value?

Also, if my goal is adding a global environment variable, is writing it to the users' `.bash_profile` the best way, that doesn't require sudo?

Answer (score 1):

If you add something like this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export MY_TEST_VAR=1213222
```

You can then execute `.bash_profile` again in the current shell context

```
. .bash_profile
```

And your new processes will see this new enviroment variable

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting is not necessary if it's not `root`'s profile you modified. You just need to log off from your desktop, or close all the sessions where you want the environment refreshed.

The user's profile files is the best way to set user-specific variables.

If you want system-wide or group-wide settings, those are best left to `root` (for system-wide) or a restricted set of users.

You could for example implement a scheme like this: Have files like the following:

```
/usr/local/etc/my_group.profile
```

readable by all users in `mygroup` but writable only by users of group `mygroup_admins`, and make the system-wide profile script source such files depending on the user's assigned groups. This gives you a bit of flexibility without having to hand out `root` privileges too much.